# Can't run Bokeh abstract rendering example - ValueError: No JSON could be decoded

Tags: python, bokeh

When I try to run the abstract rendering example in this way:

`python .\abstractrender.py`

I get this output:

```
S C:\Anaconda\Examples\bokeh\plotting\server> python .\abstractrender.py
Using saved session configuration for http://localhost:5006/
To override, pass 'load_from_config=False' to Session
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
INFO:bokeh.session:got read write apikey
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\abstractrender.py", line 9, in <module>
    output_server("abstractrender")
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bokeh\plotting.py", line 379, in output_server
    session.load_document(curdoc())
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bokeh\session.py", line 543, in load_document
    self.gc()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bokeh\session.py", line 529, in gc
    self.post_json(url)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bokeh\session.py", line 367, in post_json
    return self.execute_json('post', url, headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bokeh\session.py", line 335, in execute_json
    return utils.get_json(resp)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\bokeh\utils.py", line 41, in get_json
    return response.json()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 799, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I am running this on  Windows 7, using Continuum Analytics Anaconda, Python 2.7 and Bokeh 0.8.1.

The bokeh-server is running and I can run (e.g. .\stocks.py)

Any idea what could be wrong?

EDIT:
Spelling.

Comment: May or may not help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731262/running-a-very-simple-bokeh-server-example-using-pycharm-no-json-object-could/34731329#34731329