# Running a very simple Bokeh Server example using Pycharm - No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, pycharm, bokeh

The following code is a very simple bokeh server example retrieved from the [Specifying output_server section](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#userguide-server-output-server). It works and I get a Bokeh plot on my browser if I run `bokeh serve` in one terminal and then this code in a desperate python shell

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_server

p = figure(title="Server Plot")
p.circle([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

output_server("hover")

show(p)
```

However, when I try to run this code from pycharm I get the following traceback:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/cornelis/PycharmProjects/BrainImageAnalyzer/BokehTest.py
Using saved session configuration for http://localhost:5006/
To override, pass 'load_from_config=False' to Session
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cornelis/PycharmProjects/BrainImageAnalyzer/BokehTest.py", line 16, in <module>
    output_server("hover")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/io.py", line 169, in output_server
    docname, session=session, url=url, name=name, clear=clear
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/state.py", line 222, in output_server
    self._session.use_doc(docname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/session.py", line 455, in use_doc
    self.docid = self.find_doc(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/session.py", line 418, in find_doc
    docs = self.userinfo.get('docs')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/session.py", line 373, in userinfo
    self._userinfo = self.get_json(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/session.py", line 351, in get_json
    return self.execute_json('get', url, headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/session.py", line 335, in execute_json
    return get_json(resp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/util/serialization.py", line 88, in get_json
    return response.json()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 741, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Related, though at the time of writing, no answer posted: [Can't run Bokeh abstract rendering example - ValueError: No JSON could be decoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723365/cant-run-bokeh-abstract-rendering-example-valueerror-no-json-could-be-decode)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, well I just tried something as an afterthought and it worked. Change the interpreter to Python 3.4.0

In Pycharm, go to File -> Settings
Go to the Project Interpreter tab
From the drop-down list change the Interpreter to 3.4.0 and apply.

Upon rerunning, much to my surprise, the example works.

EDIT: I welcome anyone to modify this answer or add one below that explains why this is because as far as the docs seem to be telling me, 2.7 is supported by Bokeh.

Comment: I just tried the `plotting/server/hover.py` example that is in the repo with python 2.7 and it was working as expected. I also tried the example code you gave above in IPython (2.7) and it worked fine. There might be something about your environment, or possibly some interaction to do with PyCharm we are unaware of. Would require more investigation.